# Spliting String into different stings c#

Tags: c#, split

Please forgive me if this has been posted elsewhere, I'm new here and to coding!

In c# I wish to recieve a string like 'Hello, 15, 20' then place 'Hello' into one string, '15 in another and the '20' in another so later on in the code I can use them as variables. I've looked around and cant seem to find one that works, (or I am not using google correctly!).

Any help is much aprecieated and I hope I've made sense :P

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Bearing in mind that you're trying to *split* a string into pieces...

Comment: If only we could paste "Let me google that for you" links on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
var input = "Hello, 15, 20";
var parts = input.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

It will return an array that you can use like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(parts[0]); // "Hello";
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]); // "15";
Console.WriteLine(parts[2]); // "20";
```

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't be using google correctly.

Google `Split string c#` and you will come across `String.Split()` - [here is the msdn document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx).

```
var strs = "Hello, 15, 20".Split(new string[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g indeed, edited

Answer (score 1):

try use String.Split(), you can refer to msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

```
string stringToSplit = "Hello, 15, 20";
string[] parts = stringToSplit.Split(", ");
foreach(string part in parts)
{
  // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: Off topic, but I can't help but find `//Do your thing` hilarious for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) method to split a string into parts. The documentation on MSDN is very thorough, you should take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    string str1;
    string str2;
    string str3;

    string InputString = "Hello, 15, 20";
    string[] parts = InputString.Split(", ");

    str1 = parts[0];
    str2 = parts[1];
    str3 = parts[2];

    Console.WriteLine(str1);
    Console.WriteLine(str2);
    Console.WriteLine(str3);
```

Use Debug, if you are using WinForms like this:

```
    Debug.WriteLine(str1);
    Debug.WriteLine(str2);
    Debug.WriteLine(str3);
```